# jQuery after breaking setInterval

Tags: jquery, loops, append, setinterval

So, I made a example of a list propagation, and I totally spaced `.append()` for `.after()` so I was appending inside the master `<li>` which was very silly. However, what I thought was a one word fix... turned out to be very different. After changing `.append()` to `.after()` it will only populate once, and the interval doesn't continue.

```
var list = $('#theList li:last-child'),
    limit = 20,
    current = 0;

function rand() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2); // Just for some random contnt
}

$('#trigger').click(function() { // We're using a static button to start the population of the list
    var end = setInterval(function() {
        if ( current == limit ) {
            current = 0;
            clearInterval(end);
        }
        list.append('<li style="display:none;color:green;">' + rand() + '</li>');
        var newList = $('#theList li:last-child');
        newList.fadeIn();
        var colorEnd = setInterval(function() {
            newList.css('color', 'black');
            clearInterval(colorEnd);
        }, 350);
        current++;
    }, 300);
});
```

## Fixed Code using Jack's Suggestions [(DEMO)](http://jsfiddle.net/4PEm9/)

```
var list = $('#theList li:last-child'),
    limit = 20,
    current = 0;

function rand() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2); // Just for some random contnt
}

$('#trigger').click(function() { // We're using a static button to start the population of the list
            var end = setInterval(function() {
            if ( current == limit ) {
                current = 0;
                clearInterval(end);
            }
            var elm = $('<li style="display:none;color:green;">' + rand() + '</li>');
            list = elm.insertAfter(list);               
            elm.fadeIn();
            var colorEnd = setInterval(function() {
                    elm.css('color', 'black');
                    clearInterval(colorEnd);
            }, 350);
            current =  current + 1;
        }, 300);
});
```

## [after() Version](http://jsfiddle.net/DH5sP/)

## [append() Version](http://jsfiddle.net/erMpN/)

Comment: @Jack that too, will only populate once. I used interval, because it runs right away, and loops. I thought Timeout only runs after the timer, then continues.

Comment: `setInterval()` doesn't run the inner function immediately, btw.

Comment: @Jack Thanks. Anyways, why the strange behavior with `.after()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `list` doesn't get updated; once the first `.after()` has taken place, it no longer is the last child; the elements are still added, but they remain invisible while you keep updating the already visible element from the first iteration.

You could update it like so:

```
var el = $('<li style="display:none;color:green;">' + rand() + '</li>')

list = el.insertAfter(list);

el.fadeIn();
// etc.
```

Comment: I figured it was something similar which is why I tried declaring in the loop, but that was insane. Lol Took a minute to wrap my head around the loop of variables there but I think I get it. Calling itself sorta thing as two elements.